# C# library using IKVM has namespace ambiguity between IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary and IKVM.OpenJDK.Core

Tags: c#, java, dll, ikvm

I am using IKVM to wrap a java application into a dll.  I am not particularly familiar with IKVM so I apologize in advance for not providing enough information.  Anyway, I am using a c# library that makes a call to a dll created by IKVM.  However the library I am using appears to require both IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary and IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.  The only problem is both of these libraries contain java.util, which causes a namespace ambiguity for any class in java.util (Vectors, hastables, etc).  I cannot fine a way to reference all instances of objects found in the java.utils class to explicitly use either ClassLibrary or Core.  Is there anyway to reference a namespace to instruct my library to use one or the other for java.util calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of IKVM there is no IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary. It look like that you mix different versions of IKVM.